# Biblatex, print ISBN field in MISC entry type

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

Is it possible to force print `isbn` field in `misc` entry type? I've set `biblatex` to

```
\usepackage[authordate,backend=bibtex]{biblatex-chicago}
```

I've tried to do it with

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{misc}{\csappto{blx@bbx@\thefield{url}}{\printfield{isbn}}}}
```

It will compile, but `isbn` is not added. Maybe it needs `biber` backend, but I need `bibtex` solution. It works without `blx@bbx@`, but adds `isbn` before entry.

Edit:

Ok now it looks I'm fine with biber. Set is `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}`, but still with same problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: Sorry for asking, but if you have a isbn why do you not use `@book` instead of `@misc`? BTW: as a short workaround you can add the isbn in a `note` field ...

Comment: Yeah I know it's weird. Lets look at it as I'm interested if it's possible and how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may patch the `misc` bibliography driver so that it prints the `isbn` field if the corresponding option is set to `true`. (For convenience, I use the [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package to apply the necessary changes.) Here's a solution for `biblatex-chicago`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{misc}{%
  \usebibmacro{bib+doi+url}%
}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@isbn}%
  {\printfield{isbn}}%
  {}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{bib+doi+url}%
}{}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  isbn ={0815-4711},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use one of the core styles shipped with `biblatex`, add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{misc}{%
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
}{}{}
```

Comment: Why this works for `misc` and does not for `online`?

Comment: @user620297 Because the `online` type uses different bibmacros. Try to replace the two instances of `\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}` with `\iftoggle{bbx:eprint}` in the above code snippet.